# duda en como se estructura una clase en java

Tags: java

Estoy recién empezando a aprender java y en vez de leer 20 documentos con 200 páginas cada uno, quisiera formular una simple pregunta;

**cuales son los métodos que se pueden emplear en una clase java?**

**Por Ejemplo:**

A. Un constructor (tiene el mismo nombre de la clase)

```
public class Clase {
    public Clase() {
        //código aquí
    }
}
```

B. Método con void (no devuelve nada)

```
public class Clase {
    public void algo() {
        //código aquí
    }
}
```

C. Método con retorno (el encabezado del método lleva el tipo de dato que retorna)

```
public class Clase {
    public (tipo de valor) algo() {
        //código aquí
        retorno
    }
}
```

D. Método principal, para ejecutar el programa de Java

```
public class Clase {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        //código aquí
    }
}
```

Comment: Te faltaria un destructor.. pero cual es la pregunta? porque en general empezar diciendo no quiero investigar no es un buen metodo de preguntar...

Comment: El destructor es opcional en Java, de hecho nunca he definido uno en más de 15 años. Además es un método más, no tiene nada de especial aparte de estar definido en Object

Comment: No existen los destructores en Java amigo.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomendaría que te leyeses sólo UN manual que te explique la sintaxis de Java, porque un resumen no te va a ser de gran ayuda más que como recordatorio de lo que deberías saber, pero aquí va:

En una clase puedes definir métodos estáticos (de clase) o de instancia, además del constructor, que siempre devuelve un objeto de la clase:

```
class MiClase {
     MiClase() {}
     void método(Param p1) {...}
     static void métodoEstático(Param p) {...}
     static int métodoEstático2() { return 0;}
}
```

Si la clase es abstracta, puedes definir métodos abstractos, sin implementación para que las clases hijas las implementen:

```
abstract class MiClase {
     void abstract métodoAbstracto(Param p1);
     int abstract métodoAbstracto2();
     void métodoNormal() {...}
}
```

En una interfaz todos los métodos son abstractos a menos que quieras definir una implementación por defecto:

```
interface MiInterfaz {
   String metodo1(); //abstract se puede omitir
   default String método2() { return "";}
}
```

Y esto es todo lo importante. Existen los modificadores `final` (métodos que no se pueden sobreescribir, vienen a ser lo opuesto a `abstract`), `private`, `protected` y `public`, que indican quién puede usar estos métodos, pero no afectan a la ejecución en sí misma.

Comment: Gracias @Pablo Lozano. Ahora voy entendiendo mejor. Me he leído más de un manual, pero la información no siempre es clara en los aspectos generales.

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta cuales son los métodos que se pueden emplear en una clase java? y como se estructura esta misma.

En java la estructura básica de una clase suele seguir el siguiente esquema:

  - atributos

  - Constructores

  - Getters (accesadores).

  - Setters (mutadores).

  - métodos de clase.

Con respecto a tu pregunta **cuales son los métodos que se pueden emplear en una clase java?**

Los métodos esenciales a la hora de implementar tu clase java y que son imprescindibles pero no obligatorios son :

  - Constructores

  - Getters (accesadores).

  - Setters (mutadores).

En código la estructura básica seria de la siguiente manera:

```
 public class Persona(){
    //Atributos de la clase 
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;

    //Constructores

    //Constructor Vacio
    public Persona(){
    }

    //Constructor con Parametros
    public Persona(String nombre,int edad){
     this.nombre = nombre;
     this.edad = edad;
    } 

    //Metodos accesadores y mutadores

    public string getNombre(){
       return nombre;
    }


    public void setNombre(String nombre){
       this.nombre=nombre;
    }


    public string getEdad(){
       return edad;
    }


    public void setEdad(int edad){
       this.edad=edad;
    }




 }
```

Para que quede mas claro analizaremos el código:

Lo primero que hacemos es declarar los atributos de la clase, es recomendable
declarar los atributos al principio de la clase.

Después implementamos los constructores, puedes implementar tantos constructores como necesites, a esto se le llama **sobrecarga.**, y tu te preguntaras **para que nos servirán los constructores?** bueno nos servirán para poder instanciar nuestras clases o nuestros objetos.

Finalmente tenemos los métodos accesadores y mutadores (**getters y setters**) que son la **encapsulacion** de los atributos declarados.

Entonces los getters o get, nos permitirán obtener y mostrar lo que tiene nuestra variable declarada y los setter o set nos permitirán modificar el valor que tiene nuestra variable.

Los métodos de clase que puedes implementar son los que tu necesites. no hay un máximo o un limite de métodos.

**Te recomendaría estudiar un poco lo que es encapsulamiento, polimorfismo, programación orientada a objetos, interfaces, herencia es lo mas básico que utilizaras cuando trabajes en java.**